# What is the meaning of "#" in front of a table name in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

what is the difference between the table names "#mytable" and "mytable" in TSQL?  I see table names start with "#" in a lot of custom procedures.

Comment: Please, please, please read this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server

Answer (score 74, accepted):

These are local temporary tables which are private to the process that created them.

Answer (score 39):

#mytable is a temporary table where as mytable is a concrete table.

You can read more about [Temporary Tables in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/).

> They are used most often to provide workspace for the intermediate results when processing data within a batch or procedure. They are
>   also used to pass a table from a table-valued function, to pass
>   table-based data between stored procedures or, more recently in the
>   form of Table-valued parameters, to send whole read-only tables from
>   applications  to SQL Server routines, or pass read-only  temporary
>   tables as parameters. Once finished with their use, they are discarded
>   automatically.
>
> Temporary tables come in different flavours including, amongst others,
>   local temporary tables (starting with #), global temporary tables
>   (starting with ##), persistent temporary tables (prefixed by
>   TempDB..), and table variables.(starting with (@)