# Why do we put "#" in front of myTempTableName?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know this is a stupid questions.. But I am new to sql server...
I found the syntax online, I don't understand why....Could someone explain why we put "#" in front of myTempTableName?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#myTempTableName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     TRUNCATE TABLE #myTempTableName
END
```

Can I check if the temp table exist without '#' in front of the table name?
Can I say 'TRUNCATE TABLE myTempTableName' instead of TRUNCATE TABLE #myTempTableName?

Comment: thats the syntax to differentiate between a Table in the db and a temp table

Comment: It seems to me you could have found out if you can "check if the temp table exist without '#' in front of it" by just *trying it without the '#' in front of it*, in less time than it took you to post the question here.

Answer (score 1):

These are local temporary tables which are private to the process that created them.

#mytable is a temporary table where as mytable is a concrete table.

> You can read more about [Temporary Tables in SQL Server.](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/)
>
> They are used most often to provide workspace for the intermediate
>   results when processing data within a batch or procedure. They are
>   also used to pass a table from a table-valued function, to pass
>   table-based data between stored procedures or, more recently in the
>   form of Table-valued parameters, to send whole read-only tables from
>   applications to SQL Server routines, or pass read-only temporary
>   tables as parameters. Once finished with their use, they are discarded
>   automatically.
>
> Temporary tables come in different flavours including, amongst others,
>   local temporary tables (starting with #), global temporary tables
>   (starting with ##), persistent temporary tables (prefixed by
>   TempDB..), and table variables.(starting with (@)

SOURCE: [What is the meaning of "#" in front of a table name in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765832/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-front-of-a-table-name-in-tsql)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765832/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-front-of-a-table-name-in-tsql

Comment: @Nadeem_MK i know, hence the "SOURCE: What is the meaning of "#" in front of a table name in TSQL?" in the answer

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276245/good-or-bad-form-answering-a-question-using-another-stack-overflow-post

Comment: if its a duplicate, its better to close the question and direct the OP to the other question..hence the flag of duplicate!

Comment: Of course, but since i don't have enough rep to close or vote i just put a link to the source

Comment: For future reference, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing